# Update Firefox extension links automatically

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I am adding inline downloads for my Firefox extension on my website:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
<!--
function install (aEvent)
{
  for (var a = aEvent.target; a.href === undefined;) a = a.parentNode;
  var params = {
    "Foo": { URL: aEvent.target.href,
             IconURL: aEvent.target.getAttribute("iconURL"),
             Hash: aEvent.target.getAttribute("hash"),
             toString: function () { return this.URL; }
    }
  };
  InstallTrigger.install(params);

  return false;
}
-->
</script>
```

and the html:

```
<a id="download" href="https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/foo-0.0.4-an+fx.xpi" iconURL="icon128.png" onclick="return install(event);">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

But I am wanting that whenever I release a new update, that the link updates without me having to change it. For example a `-lastest.xpi` link? Is there such a thing or another method to get the latest link?

Comment: If your extension is validated, then the listed url of the extension does not change if you update it.

Comment: That is not true unfortunately!!

Comment: Yeap, you are right. The listed url does not change but the download link may change

Answer (score 0):

Yes you get this information via the [AMO API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Update:Remora_API_Docs)

The URL structure looks like this:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/api/[version]/addon/[id]
version = 1.5 (currently)
id = [your addon id or slug]
```

This example URL uses a slug:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/api/1.5/addon/private-tab

And this example URL uses an id, I would recommend this version.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/api/1.5/addon/422756

The information returned is everything needed to displayed on the add-on page but in an XML document.  You'll want to scan for the `install` element.

```js
    $.get('https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/api/1.5/addon/private-tab').then(function(resp) {
      $('#link').attr('href', resp.documentElement.querySelector('install').textContent);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="">DOWNLOAD</a>
```